# ptrdiff_t typedef collision - google-test and intel anaconda

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clang, googletest

## Context

I am developing a project that requires intel's anaconda distribution, and we use googletest to test our natives. I am using clang for my compiler. When I build `googletest` via `cmake`, I get this:

```
In file included from /foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:39:
In file included from /foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:58:
In file included from /foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:39:
In file included from /foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:452:
In file included from /foo/anaconda3/envs/idp3/include/regex.h:4:
/foo/anaconda3/envs/idp3/include/tclInt.h:60:16: error: typedef redefinition with different types
      ('int' vs 'long')
   typedef int ptrdiff_t;
Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/include/stddef.h:51:26: note: previous definition is here
typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
```

## My understanding of the problem

There is a typedef collision between `clang/9.1.0` and `google-test` on `ptrdiff_t`, where google includes `regex.h` which includes conda's own `tclInt.h` which has the typedef. `tclInt.h` is installed by the conda intel channel packages which we need. Uninstalling it downgrades `mkl` and `tbb` back various versions.

Here's a badly drawn dependency graph which shows where(I think) the typdef happened:

```
project native tests <-- googletest <-- regex.h <-- tclInt.h "typedef ptrdiff_t int;" 
                          ^
                          |
                   stddef.h "typedef ptrdiff_t long" (from clang)
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach this typedef collision problem and untangle it. One alternative is to use gcc-8, but even if I run `make` to build `googletest` with exported env vars:

```
CXX=g++-8
CC=gcc-8
```

the `tclInt.h` header is still pulled from the clang folder as indicated in the error dump I attached.

## Ways to solve it (?)

There are definitely other options out there that I am missing, but a possible way to solve this is to have a `tclInt.h` that doesn't have this issue, or perhaps `gcc-8` has a set of include headers that don't define `ptrdiff_t`, and there's something I can do to point to that compiler instead.

---

Note: I might be wildly wrong, but this is my hypothesis. Any help is appreciated.

If anyone wants to see the entire stacktrace, here you go:

```
In file included from /foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:39:
In file included from /foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:58:
In file included from /foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:39:
In file included from /foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:452:
In file included from /foo/anaconda3/envs/idp3/include/regex.h:4:
/foo/anaconda3/envs/idp3/include/tclInt.h:60:16: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('int' vs 'long')
   typedef int ptrdiff_t;
               ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/include/stddef.h:51:26: note: previous definition is here
typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                         ^
In file included from /foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:45:
/foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:597:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'regexec'
  return regexec(&re.full_regex_, str, 1, &match, 0) == 0;
         ^
/foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:606:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'regexec'
  return regexec(&re.partial_regex_, str, 1, &match, 0) == 0;
         ^
/foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:619:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'regcomp'
  is_valid_ = regcomp(&full_regex_, full_pattern, REG_EXTENDED) == 0;
              ^
/foo/home/bar/native/build/gradle_unittest_build/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:630:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'regcomp'
    is_valid_ = regcomp(&partial_regex_, partial_regex, REG_EXTENDED) == 0;
                ^
5 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the Tcl header file `<tclInt.h>` has preprocessor conditions which determine whether `ptrdiff_t` should be defined or `<stddef.h>` should be included:

```
#if defined(STDC_HEADERS) || defined(__STDC__) || defined(__C99__FUNC__) \
     || defined(__cplusplus) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <stddef.h>
#else
typedef int ptrdiff_t;
#endif
```

However, Intel has patched this in their `tcl-8.6.4-19.tar.bz2` distribution file to:

```
#ifdef STDC_HEADERS
#include <stddef.h>
#else
#ifdef __ICC
#  ifndef _PTRDIFF_T
#  define _PTRDIFF_T
   typedef int ptrdiff_t;
#  endif
#else
   typedef int ptrdiff_t;
#endif
#endif
```

Probably they thought they had to do something about the `_MSC_VER` dependency, although it is harmless in this context.  This works with ICC because `<stddef.h>` is provided by the compiler, and their version of the header appears to check for the `_PTRDIFF_T` macro before defining it.

Normally, this is not visible because when using `tclInt.h`, you are supposed to use the compiler flags provided by `tclConfig.sh`, which define `STDC_HEADERS`, so `<stddef.h>` is used unconditionally.

But the use of Tcl here appears entirely accidental because Intel's Tcl distribution includes a `regex.h` header which overrides the system `<regex.h>` header, and this is what googletest wants to include here.  Use of the wrong header file can lead to other problems, too.  (This is why other distributions install the Tcl headers in directories such as `/usr/include/tcl8.6` and even put the internal headers like `regex.h` into a separate subdirectory.)

I would try to deinstall the Tcl distribution from the build environment.  Hopefully it is not really needed, and so the header file collision goes away.